# In Relay.js, what is the `Client Mutation Identifier`?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

In the relay documentation [here](https://relay.dev/docs/en/graphql-server-specification#mutations), it says that:

> Relay uses a common pattern for mutations, where there are root fields on the mutation type with a single argument, input, and **where the input and output both contain a client mutation identifier** used to reconcile requests and responses.

But in the example they provided, the input and output looked like this respectively:

```
// IntroducedShipInput
{
  "input": {
    "shipName": "B-Wing",
    "factionId": "1"
  }
}

// IntroducedShipPayload
{
  "introduceShip": {
    "ship": {
      "id": "U2hpcDo5",
      "name": "B-Wing"
    },
    "faction": {
      "name": "Alliance to Restore the Republic"
    }
  }
}
```

So what is the `client mutation` identifier? And why, and how does it get used to reconcile requests and responses?

Comment: inside they are taking unique identifier name clientMutationId while perfoming mutation

Comment: @MayankPandav Can you elaborate inside what are who taking unique identifier names?

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/pdLv4GjY/Screenshot-from-2020-03-03-09-39-36.png kindly checkout it will automatically taake its value even idk what they used to take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what exactly happened to the "client mutation identifier," but having done some research, it appears to have been a requirement in previous versions of Relay. [This PR apparently removed the requirement](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/2349) by replacing it with some other mechanism, but it's not clear to me what that other mechanism does. [I left a comment requesting more clarification around the documentation](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/2349#issuecomment-613142082), which appears to be out of date.

At any rate, the client mutation identifier [appears to have been related to some assumptions about mutation idempotency in Facebook's implementation of GraphQL](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2077).